# Leer Excel con python y filtrar por un valor unico obteniendo toda la fila como lista y hacer operaciones con ella

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

Tengo un reporte que tiene diferentes informaciones en excel, pero yo voy a buscar un valor que es unico, y una vez encontrado quiero obtener todos los valores de la fila donde se encuentra ese valor y hacer operaciones con ella,por ejemplo:

[image: Excel con tabla sobre contenedor,fecha de llegada a puerto,mercancia, e importadora]

lo leo con el siguiente codigo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('d:/escritorio/colocarEXCEL/contenedores.xls', header=None,
                   sheet_name='Hoja1', skiprows=1,)

print(df)
```

y obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
    0           1                    2            3            4
0 NaN         NaN                  NaN          NaN          NaN
1 NaN  contenedor        fecha llegada    mercancia  importadora
2 NaN  aqwre12365  2020-03-02 00:00:00        pollo          KFC
3 NaN  bcftr23658  2020-02-05 00:00:00     ceramica        Mall1
4 NaN  cpooi59801  2020-02-20 00:00:00    bisuteria    MacDonals
5 NaN  drety22565  2020-04-04 00:00:00  carpinteria        Mall1
```

Quisiera poder buscar,por ejemplo, si existe el contenedor : cpooi59801 y asi poder obtener la informacion de dicho contenedor(toda la fila en una lista) y ademas comparar la fecha de llegada - fecha PC para saber cuantos dias hace que llego el contenedor..

Si no me pueden ayudar explicitamente, me pueden dar guia para estudiar alguna bibliografia?

Gracias...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar operaciones con tu dataframe, te recomiendo trabajarlos almacenandolos en una lista, para ello puedes crear un bucle para que vaya agregando los datos de tu tabla a la misma, una vez hecho esto ya puedes operar con los valores de tu tabla en código simplemente llamándolos.
Recomiendo además que no dejes espacios vacíos en tu dataframe si no es necesario, puedes comenzar colocando tus datos desde la celda A1 del excel.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime 
import pytz 
#pytz.all_timezones ---> Escribe en consola este comando y aparecerán las 
#                       distintas timezones del mundo, elige la de tu situación.

df = pd.read_excel('d:/escritorio/colocarEXCEL/contenedores.xls', header=None,
                   sheet_name='Hoja1', skiprows=1,)

print(df)
lectura = []

mi_hora = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/Guayaquil')) 

for i in df:
    lectura.append([df.values[i][0], df.values[i][1], df.values[i][2], df.values[i][3]])

# Extraccion de variables:
    contenedor = lectura[i][0]
    fecha = lectura[i][1]
    mercancia = lectura[i][2]
    importadora = lectura[i][3]
```

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Estuve leyendo un poco y he realizado lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_excel('d:/escritorio/colocarEXCEL/contenedores.xls', header=None,
                   sheet_name='Hoja1', skiprows=1,)

print(df)
print()
reporte_contenedores = df.values.tolist()
print(reporte_contenedores)

contenedor_buscar = input('Entre el contenedor a buscar en el reporte: ')

for contenedor in reporte_contenedores:

    if contenedor_buscar in contenedor:

        print('El contenedor se encuentra !!!')
        print('La mercancia es :{}'.format(contenedor[3]))
        print('La importadora es :{}'.format(contenedor[4]))
        print('Llego con fecha: {} a puerto'.format(contenedor[2]))
        print('Lleva en puerto: {} '.format(
            datetime.datetime.now() - contenedor[2]))
```

Ahora solo resta imprimir mensaje cuando no se encuentre el contenedor, asi como un while para que siempre pida buscar uno..

Esto es un ejercicio de prueba, el verdadero reporte tendra mucha mas informacion, y no sera en este orden, pero algo es algo

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si se usa Pandas, lo normal por eficiencia, simplicidad y escalabilidad es seguir usando Pandas a no ser que sea algo que no podamos realizar sin recurrir a contenedores o ciclos propios de Python estándar. Usar Pandas solo para leer un xlsx es ineficiente, si vamos a trabajar con Pandas, mejor usar `openpyxl` directamente.

Lo primero es cargar de forma adecuada el Excel, es importante que indiques correctamente la fila con las cabeceras para facilitar el acceso a los datos, en tu caso:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    'd:/escritorio/colocarEXCEL/contenedores.xls',
    header=0,
    sheet_name='Hoja1',
    skiprows=2,
    usecols="B:E"
    )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>    contenedor    llegada    mercancia importador
> 0  aqwre12365 2020-03-02        pollo        KFC
> 1  bcftr23658 2020-02-05     ceramica      Mall1
> 2  cpooi59801 2020-02-20    bisuteria  MacDonals
> 3  drety22565 2020-04-04  carpinteria      Mall1
>
> >>> df.columns
> Index(['contenedor', 'llegada', 'mercancia', 'importador'], dtype='object')
> ```

Buscar si una columna tiene un valor determinado y obtener la fila es trivial:

> ```
> >>> df[df['contenedor'] ==  "cpooi59801"]
>
>    contenedor    llegada  mercancia importador
> 2  cpooi59801 2020-02-20  bisuteria  MacDonals
> ```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    'd:/escritorio/colocarEXCEL/contenedores.xls',
    header=0,
    sheet_name='Hoja1',
    skiprows=2,
    usecols="B:E"
    )

while busqueda:= input('Entre el contenedor a buscar en el reporte o pulse Enter para salir: '):
    cont = df[df['contenedor'] == busqueda]
    if not cont.empty:
        print('¡El contenedor se ha encuentrado!')
        print(f'La mercancia es: {cont.at[cont.index[0], "mercancia"]}')
        print(f'La importadora es: {cont.at[cont.index[0], "importador"]}')
        print(f'Llego con fecha: {cont.at[cont.index[0], "llegada"]}')
        print(f'Lleva en puerto: {pd.datetime.now() - cont.at[cont.index[0], "llegada"]}\n')
    else:
        print('¡El contenedor no se ha encontrado!\n')
```

> ```
> Entre el contenedor a buscar en el reporte o pulse Enter para salir: bcftr23658
> ¡El contenedor se ha encuentrado!
> La mercancia es: ceramica
> La importadora es: Mall1
> Llego con fecha: 2020-02-05 00:00:00
> Lleva en puerto: 87 days 13:17:01.228088
> ```

Pandas te facilitará mucho la tarea si quieres realizar filtros más complejos d forma eficiente. Por ejemplo, si quieres obtener el contenedor que lleva más tiempo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    'contenedores.xls',
    header=0,
    sheet_name='Hoja1',
    skiprows=2,
    usecols="B:E"
    )

tiempo = pd.datetime.now() - df["llegada"]
idx_max = tiempo.idxmax()
print(f"El contenedor más antiguo es {df.at[idx_max, 'contenedor']}")
print(f"Tiempo desde llegada: {tiempo[idx_max]}")
print(f"Importador: {df.at[idx_max, 'importador']}")
print(f"Contenido: {df.at[idx_max, 'mercancia']}")
```

> ```
> El contenedor más antiguo es bcftr23658
> Tiempo desde llegada: 87 days 13:29:38.435255
> Importador: Mall1
> Contenido: ceramica
> ```